# XSLT sourcing localisation strings from a secondary xml file

Tags: xml, xslt

This is best demonstrated by a short example.

The main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
  </cd>
</catelo>
```

The secondary XML, let's call it `localisation.es.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localisation lang="es">
    <field id="title">Título</field>
    <field id="artist">Artista</field>
</localisation>
```

The desired output:

```
<html>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>   <td>Título</td>            <td>Artista</td>      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>   <td>Empire Burlesque</td>  <td>Bob Dylan</td>    </tr>
      <tr>   <td>Hide your heart</td>   <td>Bonnie Tyler</td> </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

As you can see, the data is sourced from the main XML file, while the localisation strings for the field names are from the secondary XML. How would XSLT be written to handle the case?

---

Furthermore, what if the fields are unknown to the XSLT? Say, someone added a new field `<year>` for every record in the main XML, and added a line for it in the `localisation.es.xml`:

```
    <field id="year">Año</field>
```

Is it possible to generate the desired output without modifying the XSLT file?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your processor support XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using lookup tables, this requires XSLT 2.0.

In your xslt you would create a key, and a variable containing the lookup table(s)( in this case your localisation file). Whenever you need a file from the lookup tables you can then search the correct value using the key.

So first define the variable and the key.

```
<xsl:variable name="localisation" select="document('localisation.es.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="locKey" match="localisation/field" use="@id"/>
```

Then when you need to find the string for title you would select it as follows

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('locKey', 'title', $lookup)"/>
```

Comment: Note that this requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: You are correct of course, added mention of that to the answer